Getting BadrequestError / Valueerror while fetching response from AzureOpenAI with langchain
For the below Code:
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAI
llm = AzureOpenAI(model_name='gpt-35-turbo-instruct', api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"), api_version=os.getenv('OPENAI_API_VERSION'), azure_endpoint=os.getenv('AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'))

from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

loader = PyPDFLoader('./genai.pdf')
text_documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=100)
documents = text_splitter.split_documents(text_documents)

from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
db = FAISS.from_documents(documents, HuggingFaceEmbeddings())

retriever = db.as_retriever()

from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
retrieval_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type='stuff',
    retriever=retriever,
    verbose=True,
)

When I am trying to fetch response using this:
result = retrieval_chain({'messages':'What is genAI?'})
result['result']

or
result = retrieval_chain({
    'messages': [
        {'role': 'system', 'content': 'You are a helpful assistant.'},
        {'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is genAI?'}
    ]
})

I am getting ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'query'}
When I am trying this approach :
result = retrieval_chain({
    'query':'what are usecases of genai?'
})

or
result = retrieval_chain({
    'messages': [
        {'role': 'system', 'content': 'You are a helpful assistant.'},
        {'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is genAI?'}
    ],
    'query':'what are usecases of genai?'
})

I am getting **BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "'messages' is a required property", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
**
Could you please help me I have tried many methods but nothing is working I am getting either of these errors.
How can I resolve this error and what is the core problem in this?
